# What is the reason for mysql connection timeout using nodejs and RDS database

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-rds, connection-timeout

I was connecting to mysql database and everything was fine. Suddenly, I started to get the TIMEOUT error. So, I try to connect using a simple test code. The code is:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host:'RDS HOST',
                user:'user',
                password:'password',
                database:'database'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/sql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:419:13)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/sql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/sql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/sql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/sql-test/sql-test.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

Some points:

- My RDS Database is working fine and there are no security group
  blocking the connection. I can connect to my RDS Database throw MySql
  Workbeanch or PHPMYADMIN with no problem.
- The code is correct. If I change the host for my mysql server running on localhost, I get no error.

Does anybody have an ideia of what else can be the reason for this error?

Comment: Could it be a timeout setting in RDS? Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590152/error-connecting-to-amazon-rds-mysql-from-node-mysql

Comment: I don't think so. I change of wifi connection and the same code worked. So I rebooted my internet and it worked again. Now, I do not know what caused this sudden error. But a reboot in the modem solved.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but from github actions.  I can connect to my RDS instance fine with the mysql client, but not from nodejs with the same settings.  It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I thought I would answer it since I had this problem with RDS databases in the past. You need to end the connections to RDS.  If you don't, and dont handle the error, nodeJS will exit.

```
  con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Connection Failed");
      var response = {
        status: 400,
        success: "Failed!",
        message: "CONNECTION_FAILURE",
      };
      console.log(err.stack);
      con.end(function(err) {
        if (err) {
        }
      });
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
    } else console.log("Connected!");
    con.query("SELECT 0", function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        var response = {
          status: 400,
          success: "Failed!",
          message: "CONNECTION_FAILURE",
        };
        console.log(err.stack);
        con.end(function(err) {
          if (err) {
          }
        });
        return res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    });
```